# Simplify code for use in other controllers

Tags: php, laravel

Would it be possible to simplify this for use in the various controllers methods?

```
$eventId = request()->route('event');
$event = Event::where('id', $eventId)->first();
if($event->finish == 0) {
    return $content
        ->header(__('Timing'))
        ->description(__('List'))
        ->body($this->grid());
}
else {
    return $content
            ->header(__('Start list'))
            ->description(__('List'))
            ->body(view('admin.events.finished'));
}
```

The only thing that changes would be the header, description and the body
 when finish is equal to 0, the else is the same for all.

Thanks

Comment: Seems like it could be theoretically possible to build a re-usable function to do this. But I'd suggest from experience that trying to do so is probably more bother than it's worth. You're likely to find that it works great for the first three instances, and then the next three all have some little variance from what you have, and before you know it you either have an overly complicated function that deals with all the possibilities or else you have a function that's only used in a couple of places because it's not quite applicable to anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the gist in a model, then call it whenever you need it.

```
public function event ($eventId){
   $event = Event::where('id', $eventId)->first();

   if($event->finish == 0) {
     $outcome = $content ->header(__('Timing')) 
          ->description(__('List')) ->body($this->grid()); 

  } else { 
    $outcome = $content ->header(__('Start list')) 
            ->description(__('List'))
             ->body(view('admin.events.finished')); 
  }

   return $outcome;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't too much logic in your controller so it's not all bad. But yes you can. Few things I notice is `$event->finish == 0` i would create a scope on your model as the first thing

```
public function isFinished()
{
    return $this->finish == 0;
}
```

How exactly are you getting the EventId? I would imagine it's passed in a parameter? So you should be able to get it as a dependency?

```
public function YourcontrollerFunction(Request $request, $eventId)
{
    //Either you get the request from a parameter or the $request->event_id
}
```

so a small refactoring would look like this in total:

```php
public function YourcontrollerFunction(Request $request, $eventId)
{
    $event = Event::findOrFail($eventId);
    if($event->isFinished()) {
        return $content
           ->header(__('Timing'))
           ->description(__('List'))
           ->body($this->grid());
    }
//No need for the else.
   return $content
     ->header(__('Start list'))
     ->description(__('List'))
     ->body(view('admin.events.finished'));
}
```

If the response are used a lot, you could make a Response class, which is stored aswell, but don't see a reason for this here.